# How to dynamically initialize Variables in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to run some optimization procedure in Tensorflow for a batch of examples, and I already have some raw estimation of these variables to optimize. So I want to initialize the variables with these estimated values, instead of some random numbers or zero.

So I wonder how can I make it? Please note here the initialization value is sample-dependent. My plan is to feed the initialization to some placeholder, then initialize the variable from this placeholder, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the operation `update_estimates = tf.assign(variable,estimated_value)`, where `estimated_value` is a `tf.placeholder` that will contain your guess in the form of numpy arrays.

You then do a simple
`sess.run(update_estimates, feed_dict={estimated_value:numpy_array})`.

`tf.get_variable()` can be very useful, but for beginners I would advise against it.

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what I want! Thus every dynamic variable can be controlled centrally in a consistent manner: via placeholder and fee_dict. I believe this is some good programming practice.

Comment: Hm, do you know how to run **tf.assign** operation in combination with **tf.contrib.opt.ScipyOptimizerInterface** (refer to as optimizer)? To run **optimizer.minimize**, one needs to pass **seesion** instance as one parameter. And here **tf.assign** operation needs to be run before **optimizer.minimize**. Seems **optimizer.minimize** doesn't accept an list of "pre-operations" to conduct.

Comment: Use `tf.control_dependencies()` to run updates before another operation.

Answer (score 1):

I belive that this could be a good start for your problem:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

#This should be your raw estimation for the variables.
#Here I am using random numers as an example.
estimated_raw = np.random.uniform(-1,1,[2,3])

#This trainable variable will be initialized with estimated_raw
var = tf.get_variable('var', initializer=estimated_raw)

# Testing if everything is ok
with tf.Session() as sess:
  var.initializer.run()
  print(var.eval())
```

In this way you have initialized a variable with your estimation. The optimizer will take it further.

Comment: Yes, I bet this works. Still I want some "pure" Tensorflow way, like somehow one can pass the initialization value through placeholder or some other inherent Tensorflow mechanism. If possible I suppose the program can be more structured and easier to modify.